Confusion regarding error in Little Professor exercise (CS50P Problem Set 4)
I'm working on the "Little Professor" exercise from Problem Set 4 of the CS50P course, and I’m encountering an error message that I don't quite understand. The program inputs  10 random answers to math problems, but then I receive an error because the program doesn't exit automatically after the 10 inputs.
I’m unsure if I’m misunderstanding the check, but it seems irrelevant to the logic of my program. Can anyone help clarify why this check is being made, and how I can fix it?
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!
this is my code
import random
import sys

levels = {'1','2','3'}
random.seed(0)

def main():
    level = get_level()
    numbers = generate_integer(level)

    score = 0

    for i in range(10):
        lifes = 3
        x = random.choice(numbers)
        y = random.choice(numbers)
        calculation = (f"{x} + {y} = ")

        while lifes > 0:
            answer = (input(calculation))

            if answer.isalpha() or int(answer) != (x + y):
                print("EEE")
                lifes -= 1

            else:
                score = score + 1
                break

        if lifes == 0:
            print(f"{x} + {y} = {x + y}")

    sys.exit(f"Score: {score}")


def get_level():
    output = input("Level: ")
    while output not in levels:
        output = input('Level: ')
    return int(output)

def generate_integer(level):
    # 0-9, 10-99, 100-999
    if level == 1:
        numbers = range(0, 9)
    elif level == 2:
        numbers = range(10, 99)
    elif level == 3:
        numbers = range(100, 999)
    return numbers


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


this is the exercise:
"In a file called professor.py, implement a program that:
Prompts the user for a level,

If the user does not input 1, 2, or 3, the program should prompt again.
Randomly generates ten (10) math problems formatted as X + Y = , wherein each of X and Y is a non-negative integer with digits. No need to support operations other than addition (+).
Prompts the user to solve each of those problems. If an answer is not correct (or not even a number), the program should output EEE and prompt the user again, allowing the user up to three tries in total for that problem. If the user has still not answered correctly after three tries, the program should output the correct answer.
The program should ultimately output the user’s score: the number of correct answers out of 10.

Structure your program as follows, wherein get_level prompts (and, if need be, re-prompts) the user for a level and returns 1, 2, or 3, and generate_integer returns a randomly generated non-negative integer with level digits or raises a ValueError if level is not 1, 2, or 3:"
The program expects three attempts per question, yet providing the wrong answer and only providing 10 inputs always leads to waiting until exit. This creates a contradiction in the program's logic.

There's nothing obviously wrong with your code - but perhaps the testing software is being confused by the fact that you're exiting with an exception?  Try getting rid of sys.exit(), just print the score message and let the main() function complete normally.
